# I Get "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" Error on "@main.result_callback()" When executing run.sh for SimpleNet

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, python-3.8, python-click

I am trying yo run SimpleNet network and when I enter the command `bash run.sh` on the terminal I see the following output:

```
Matplotlib created a temporary cache directory at /tmp/matplotlib-ovjj_rt5 because the default path (/home/username/.config/matplotlib) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and to better support multiprocessing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    @main.result_callback()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Steps to Produce**

1. Install WSL 20.04 on a Windows 11 computer.
2. Install python 2.7 and 3.8.10 in WSL
3. Build OpenCV 4.2.0 from sources with python support.
4. Clone this repository [here](https://github.com/DonaldRR/SimpleNet) into home directory.
5. Install required packages listed [here](https://github.com/DonaldRR/SimpleNet?tab=readme-ov-file#environment) with pip3.
6. Download the [MVTech dataset](https://www.mvtec.com/company/research/datasets/mvtec-ad/) into a newly created directory under your home directory.
7. Extract the tar archive with the command `tar -xf mvtec_anomaly_detection.tar.xz` inside the directory into which you have downloaded the dataset.
8. Edit first and tenth lines of run.sh to make it point to the dataset I have just downloaded.
9. Enter the command `bash run.sh`
10. See the error on your terminal

**Envirovment:**

- WSL 20.04
- Python 3.8.10
- OpenCV 4.2.0 (Built from source)
- Torch 1.12.1
- Torchvision 0.13.1
- numpy 1.22.4

**What Did I Try?**

- I have tried to debug main.py code.

I have seen that up until `@main.result_callback()`, it was working as expected

- Searched If it have happened to someone else

I have seen that someone have solved the issue [here](https://github.com/DonaldRR/SimpleNet/issues/40). But, I couldn't understand what exactly they did to solve the issue.

**What I Have Expected**

I have expected that as I run the command `bash run.sh` I would see that the network begin it's training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a version of `click` package later than `8.0.4`.

The `Group.resultcallback` method was renamed to `Group.result_callback` in versions of `click` package greater than `8.0.4`, .